# Autocad "Aligned" Constraint - distance between two parallel lines

Tags: autocad

I am creating the 3d Design in Autodesk Autocad 2017. I need to specify distance between two parallel lines, I could successfully defined the parallel constraint but not able to add constraint that would restrict the distance between them. As per documentation [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-F22AD919-40DF-4AC3-8339-CD212D79EB94-htm.html) we can use "Aligned" constraint to restrict the distance between point-point/point-line/line-line.

> Aligned Constrains the length of a line or the distance between two
>   lines, a point on an object and a line, or two points on different
>   objects.
>
> Point & Line Selects a point and a line object. The aligned constraint
>   controls the distance between a point and the closest point on a line.

But when I try this constraint I am not able to select the line but the closest point on line gets auto selected. Now these parallel lines end at different points on sketch and in turn results in Constraint which just defines the distance between line end points which is not desirable.

I need perpendicular distance between two parallel lines to be constrained. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

With your *aligned constraint* command active, press the down arrow on your keyboard and you will see a dropdown with options like this:

[image]

Make sure that *Dynamic Input* is switched on to see the feedback at your cursor instead of the command bar at the bottom.